# "Run" HTMLUnit with PHP

Tags: java, php, htmlunit

So I have installed Java on my CentOS server.  I now want to be able to use PHP to run HTMLUnit to get a fully rendered webpage and then return the results to the user.

I see the "simple" example on HTMLUnit but I know next to nothing about Java and don't know where that needs to go or be ran to even get the test case working (i.e. getting Google's homepage).

```
public void getURL() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://google.com"); // Pass in URL

    // RETURN "page"
}
```

Once the test is working I would need to be able to "pass" in the desired URL and then "capture" the output.

So far Googling as me running in circles.  Does anyone have a link to a simple example, and then pointers on how to integrate it with PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [shell_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php) call to start HTMLunit console line and capture the output. As for the code, this should get you started:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.String;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

public class myClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create and initialize WebClient object
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://google.com"); // Pass in URL
        Console.out.println(page.toString());
    }   
}
```

Then, from php:

```
$html = shell_exec('/bin/javac myClient.java');
```

I can't test it at the moment, so sorry for any code mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Get HTML using java

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.lang.String;

    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

    public class GetHtml {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://google.com"); // Pass in URL
            String originalHtml = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
            System.out.println(originalHtml);
        }

    }
```

Get result from php

```
    exec("java -jar ", $output);
```

$output is your expected data.